# Bad return type in lambda expression: Cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java, android, lambda

I need to change the shapeType by touching the button. I tried this method but I got an error which says that the shapeType cannot be converted to boolean. 
Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArFragment arFragment;

private enum ShapeType {
    GIRAFFE,
    HIPPO,
    ELEPHANT
}

private ShapeType shapeType = ShapeType.GIRAFFE;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

    Button giraffe = findViewById(R.id.giraffebutt);
    Button hippo = findViewById(R.id.hippobutt);
    Button elephant = findViewById(R.id.elephantbutt);

    giraffe.setOnTouchListener(view -> shapeType = ShapeType.GIRAFFE);
    hippo.setOnTouchListener(view ->shapeType = ShapeType.HIPPO);
    elephant.setOnTouchListener(view ->shapeType = ShapeType.ELEPHANT);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Bad return type in lambda expression: ShapeType cannot be converted to boolean
```

Comment: A touch listener should return a boolean value. Change your lambda expressions to do this.

Comment: `view -> { shapeType = ShapeType.GIRAFFE; return false;}` should do it. same thing for the other 2 lambdas

Comment: Not sure about the android construct specifically, yet even `shapeType == ShapeType.GIRAFFE` shall do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onTouch()` methods expects to return a boolean right now you are not returning any thing change your lambda as follows.

```
giraffe.setOnTouchListener(
(view, motionEvent) -> {
    shapeType = ShapeType.GIRAFFE;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: it expects return statement if I remove return.

Answer (score 0):

The Button's `setOnTouchListener` provides a `View` and `MotionEvent`, and expects a `boolean` return type.

```
giraffe.setOnTouchListener((view, event) -> {
    shapeType = ShapeType.GIRAFFE);
    return true; // return true if event is consumed, false otherwise
});
```